# get domain substring using javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am trying to parse a domain that has more than two period's in the string.

So for example, I am trying to get `sjmktmail-batch1a.marketo.org` into `marketo.org`

I tried using split and a range from the list like this:

```
testdata = sjmktmail-batch1a.marketo.org
testdata.split(".")[1:2]
```

but that didn't work.
doing `testdata.split(".")[1]` brings up `marketo` but I want `marketo.org`

**Sorry, my main language is python, so some javascript concepts confuse me. I assume you can't get a range of an array/list by using [x:x]**

My main goal is to get a domain like `domain.com`

so for example:

fdasdadio.conglomo.com would be `conglomo.com`
billy.fdaoco.codsaso.mainbug.com would be `mainbug.com`
purple.red.bri.noschool.edu would be `noschool.edu`

Pretty sure I am missing a concept that would make this easy.

Comment: What is difference between `sjmktmail-batch1a.marketo.org` &  `sjmktmail-batch1a.marketo.org`

Comment: [What research have you done and how did it fail you?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by a chain of `split`, `slice`, `join`. like this:

`slice(-2)` means get two last items from array.

```js
const str = 'billy.fdaoco.codsaso.mainbug.com';
const domain = str.split('.').slice(-2).join('.');
console.log(domain)
```

Answer (score 1):

One line code:

```
"sjmktmail-batch1a.marketo.org".split('.').slice(1).join('.')
```

```js
    const input = "sjmktmail-batch1a.marketo.org";
    var data =input.split('.')      // ["sjmktmail-batch1a", "marketo", "org"]
    data = data.slice(1);           // ["sjmktmail-batch1a"]
    const output = data.join('.');  // "marketo.org"
    console.log(output);
```

Comment: I'd use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) over [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and as `splice` changes the original array there is no need to reassign the variable.

Comment: @JonP, updated as suggested, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as splitting the string, and getting the last two elements of the string, right?

```js
var str = "sjmktmail-batch1a.marketo.org"
var arr = str.split(".");
console.log(arr[arr.length-2]+"."+arr[arr.length-1])
```